# ActionBar menu appearing 2 times one at top and second at bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application appearing very strange problem.

I am using Action Bar with the help of "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;"

Now issue is same menu appearing two times. one is at top and second is at bottom. I want that menu at only top area.

Below is the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

My code for setting Action Bar is here:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setTitle(title);

        if(isBackToHome)
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        else{
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the targetSdkVersion to 14 or above in your 'ApplicationManafest'

Comment: thanks a lot. your given suggestion worked. thank you very much. you are champ. :D

Comment: OK great! Glad to hear it.